# With which word versions is a VSTO Plugin compatible?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I have developed a VSTO Plugin for Microsoft Word. Now I want to check the compatibility of this plugin with Word. How can I find out, with which Word versions my Plugin is compatible with?

Thank and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects in case of VSTO add-ins:

1. The VSTO runtime. COM add-ins can be run in Word 2000 and above. To find out with what Word versions your add-in is compatible you need to check where VSTO is supported. It depends on the .net runtime version of course, but the [Run solutions in different versions of Microsoft Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/running-solutions-in-different-versions-of-microsoft-office?view=vs-2022) page lists supported Office versions depending on the VSTO version and target .net framework used.
2. The Word object model. As for the host application, you need to review your code and check what properties and methods are used. Typically the minimum supported version corresponds to the Word interop version you have used in your solution. If you try to run your solution in an earlier Word version there is a chance to call a property or method which was introduced in later versions.
3. The installer. In your installer you may configure the minimum required version. Depending on that you may figure out the supported versions of Word.

Comment: Thanks for the link "Run solutions in different versions of Microsoft Office" I hadn't found this. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It will be compatible with at least the version of Word that you added as a reference to your project references. It will also likely work fine with the previous versions if you avoid using newer-version specific features.

If you have a particular minimum version that you want to support, create an interop dll on a machine where that version is installed and then add that interop dll to your VSTO addin project references instead of adding Word Object Model library from the COM tab.